# Getting two strings from Xpath

Tags: javascript, html, xpath

I need to get two paths from Xpath and I know that separating them with a comma doesn't work, so maybe someone smarter can tell me how to get those two paths.

```
<tr>
    <td valign="top" style='width: 240px;'>ravimite manustamine i/m, i/v, s/c, per/os, per/rectum</td>
    <%
    Element elemText = xml.getElementsFromXPath("//nursing_care/ravimite_manustamine/tekst" , "//nursing_care/ravimite_manustamine/kuupaev");
    %>
    <td valign="top">
        <input><%=(elemText==null?"checked=\"checked\"":"") %> value="0" onclick="javascript:showText(this);" name="//nursing_care/ravimite_manustamine" type="radio" checked="checked">Valimata
        <input><%=(elemText!=null?"checked=\"checked\"":"") %> value="1" onclick="javascript:showText(this);" name="//nursing_care/ravimite_manustamine" type="radio">Määratud
    </td>
    <td>
        <textarea style='width: 300px' style="display:<%=(elemText==null?" none":"block") %>" id="//nursing_care/ravimite_manustamine/tekst" name="//nursing_care/ravimite_manustamine/tekst"><%=(elemText!=null?elemText.getText():"") %></textarea>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" class="txt_left" style="display:<%=(elemText==null?" none":"block") %>" id="//nursing_care/ravimite_manustamine/kuupaev"  name="//nursing_care/ravimite_manustamine/kuupaev" value="<%=xml.getText("//nursing_care/ravimite_manustamine/kuupaev")%>" maxlength="10" size="10"
        onchange="gnlDateValid(this,event); if(event.returnValue != false);" onfocus="gnlGotFocus(getCurrentDate(),this); inputChanged(this);" onkeydown="gnlKeyDown('00.00.0000',this,event);" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Please could you post a sample of your XML dataset so that we can have a look at the correct xpath to use?

Comment: Could you say something about what is going wrong ? any error message?

Comment: Hmm i don't really understand what you mean. Why can't you just call the function twice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method to use is selecting all elements under the node, then filtering by the "self" to ensure the node name matches what you want.

You may also return an IEnumerable when selecting multiple nodes:

```
var elements = xml.getElementsFromXPath("//nursing_care/ravimite_manustamine/*[self::tekst or self::kuupaev]");
```

You should then be able to iterate through this list.